# Right-justifying a number with dot leaders

Tags: python, comparative-review, formatting, floating-point

I'm working on a small library to help me format numbers easier as my current project deals with a lot of them.  I want to be able to just supply the value, precision, width, and fillchar to a method and have it do all the work for me.

---

Based on the standard way of doing things with `rjust()`…

> ```
> print '{:.2f}'.format(123.456).rjust(10, '.')
> # ....123.46
> ```

… I could write:

```
def float_rjust(value, width, precision=2, fillchar=' ', separator='', sign=''):
    #[sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
    spec = '{{:{1}{2}{3}.{4}f}}'.format(
        sign,
        width,
        separator,
        precision
    )
    return spec.format(value).rjust(width, fillchar)
```

---

However, I have found that the `format()` method actually allows for justifications in it:

> ```
> print '{:.>10.2f}'.format(123.456)
> # ....123.46
> ```

… so I could also write it this way:

```
def float_rjust(value, width, precision=2, fillchar=' ', separator='', sign=''):
    #[[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
    spec = '{{:{0}>{1}{2}{3}.{4}f}}'.format(
        fillchar,
        sign,
        width,
        separator,
        precision
    )
    return spec.format(value)
```

---

My main question is, should I used the `[[fill]align]` formatting spec in `format()` to do justification, or is it more Pythonic to use `format().rjust()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of efficiency, the second form is probably *slightly* better, as it creates fewer string objects:

```
def float_rjust(value, width, precision=2, fillchar=' ', separator='', sign=''):
    #[sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
    spec = '{{:{1}{2}{3}.{4}f}}'.format(  # 1
        sign,
        width,
        separator,
        precision
    )  # 2
    value = spec.format(value)  # 3 - slight refactor for clarity
    return value.rjust(width, fillchar)  # 4
```

vs.

```
def float_rjust(value, width, precision=2, fillchar=' ', separator='', sign=''):
    #[[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
    spec = '{{:{0}>{1}{2}{3}.{4}f}}'.format(  # 1
        fillchar,
        sign,
        width,
        separator,
        precision
    )  # 2
    return spec.format(value)  # 3
```

In general terms, I would use e.g. `rjust` only where that was the **only** formatting I required; it seems awkward to split the formatting into two steps.

---

However, I would probably rearrange this completely. You have combined two steps that I think should probably be separate: creating a specification, and applying it to an object.

Using `format(value, spec)` rather than `spec.format(value)` (i.e. [the `format` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) vs. [the `str.format` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)) lets you simplify the `spec` (getting rid of the extra braces):

```
def float_spec(width, precision=2, fillchar=' ', separator='', sign=''):
    """Create a specification for formatting floats."""
    return '{}>{}{}{}.{}f'.format(fillchar, sign, width, separator, precision)
```

You can now inline the `format` call:

```
>>> print format(123.456, float_spec(width=10, fillchar='.'))
....123.46
```

For greater efficiency, as `float_spec` would return equal (but *not* identical) strings for the same inputs, you could add memoization/caching. You could also add validation (of either the parameters or created `spec`s) to ensure that it outputs a valid specification for `format`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was in the process of splitting everything up when you left this. Here is what I've finally finished with. [float_formatting.py](https://gist.github.com/bnlucas/798404302b20606c1101)

Comment: @bnlucas you can ask a follow-up question if you like - see e.g. http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1066/32391. I certainly have more feedback for you!